# Issue in querying without fragmentation in MarLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have a document like the following:

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <id>1</id>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <id>2</id>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <id>3</id>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

I am running the following query:

```
cts:search(/employees/employee,
           cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id"),("2")),"unfiltered")
```

It returns:

```
<employee><id>1</id></employee>
```

I know setting `employee` as a fragment root will return me the employee with id 2. But I can't understand why this unfiltered search w/o fragmentation gives only the first employee element. Please help.

ML version: 8.0-1.1

Comment: Filtering is supported for precisely this use case. Running filtered would perform better than filtering after the fact with XPath.  But, as David, points out, a much better solution is to model the data so each document stores the equivalent of an RDB row instead of an RDB table. Put the documents in a collection for an equivalent to an RDB table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For good or bad, that is how unfiltered search works..

> An unfiltered search. 
>   An unfiltered search selects fragments from the
>   indexes that are candidates to satisfy the specified cts:query, and
>   then it returns a single node from within each fragment that
>   satisfies the specified searchable path expression.

(Note the phrase **single node**)

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search

The rest of the description gives more details about when unfiltered results give unpredictable results. But in general, anything other than a top-level node(employee**s** in your case) is likely to not yield predictable results.

If you really want to get back employee 2 and use unfiltered searches, then set your searchable expression to doc() and filter the result via xPath. But be warned about the overhead in this for large docs of employees (or any other data for that matter).  In general, to use unfiltered searches, you should have your data structured differently(suggested) or fragment roots otherwise.

Comment: Thank you David for responding on a Sunday.It's just a mocked up data model ,and in the real model every employee has an XML.  Was just trying out stuff around the idea of fragments and came across this this.